# How to Implement Icon Overlay

Tags: c#

I am developing a Windows project but I am really stuck with the Icon Overlay concept. I have searched many articles but finally most of the members suggested to below link:

- [How to overlay an icon over existing shell objects in 3 easy steps](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7484/How-to-overlay-an-icon-over-existing-shell-objects)

However I can't understand how to use it from C#. Could you please help me?

Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to add overlays in the shell (i.e. Windows Explorer), or are you trying to use icon overlays in your own ListView inside a WinForms application? (Or are you using WPF or Silverlight or LightSwitch?)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example in C#, although I apologise its more of a code dump than an explanation of how to do it.

http://alski.net/post/2012/01/11/WPF-Icon-Overlays.aspx

The important bit is this which takes a Visual and converts it into a bitmap. The IconOverlay is bound to the generated bitmap.

```
 public static BitmapSource GenerateBitmapSource(Visual visual, double renderWidth, double renderHeight)
    {
        var bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)renderWidth, (int)renderHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        var dv = new DrawingVisual();
        using (DrawingContext dc = dv.RenderOpen())
        {
            dc.DrawRectangle(new VisualBrush(visual), null, new Rect(0, 0, renderWidth, renderHeight));
        }
        bmp.Render(dv);
        return bmp;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As i already [wrote here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8906978/57488), you can simply take a look [into the sources](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisesvn/source/browse/TortoiseOverlays/version-1.1.3/IconOverlay.cpp) of [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) to find how to do this.