# Video thumbnail with custom image overlay

Tags: c#, shell-extensions

I want to overlay an image over a video thumbnail. Like the image shown below which is a video thumbnail having WMP image shown in right bottom.

[image]

Is there is any way to overlay video thumbnail with custom WMP image shown on video thumbnail. as shown in above attached image,Any library or way to do this in c#?

Comment: Are you looking for this kind of information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258628/how-to-implement-icon-overlay ?

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using an overlay image that matches the size of the video thumbnail and is transparent except for the WMP icon? This way you can programmatically add your overlay at the same coordinates (aligned at upper left corner).
.png format works well for this purpose.