# Changing application's Icon and Name after installation

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a oneclick application that is being distribuited in a lot of versions that basically share 99% of the code, and differ only for some personalization like icon, name, and little other.

Mantaining the code aligned in all versions is getting too much time comsuming, so I would like to build a basic neutral application, that during the first start ask what version to install and then applies the changes.
My only problem is that I don't know how to change the icon, and the application name *after* that the application has been installed.

It's even possible?

Comment: you want to change the application title bar icon ? or the icon that is shown in taskbar or file icon ?

Comment: The icons in the start menu and taskbar

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [Change File Icons in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292430/change-file-icons-in-c-sharp)

Comment: And for the assebly name?

Comment: Do you mean name of your exe or dll?

Comment: The name that appears in the start menu and in the taskbar

Comment: you can use **Proprocessor Directive #if** while building the assembly.